# Can someone "proofhear" an audio?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm preparing an application where people can proofread other people's texts, but they can also review other's audios as well. Review could be a good word to use, but I'm already using this to... well, review, visual contents.

This kind of reviews are always cross checks, I mean, you'd never have to validate your own contents, but you do accept/reject other people's ones.

So, the question is:

**Is there a direct equivalent of *proofread*, but focused on audios?**

Comment: Good question. But if there isn't, would you settle for something that is not up to your specifications?

Comment: There are always apt substitutes.

Comment: @vickyace well of course, I could stick to "Review audios", of course. But because of the interface design, the less words, the better

Comment: **Transcription proofreading**, exists. But that works in two steps. First write down what is heard. Then proofread the written text. Also there may be digital versions of it, so technically no written text may be visible.

Comment: @NVZ But what I'm looking for is a word that refers to "reviewing an audio", for instance, playing it and deciding if there's background noise, it's hard to understand, etc.

Comment: How exactly does this proofreading service of yours work? Users listen to other users' audio and record a corrected version by themselves? Or do they write it down?

Comment: @NVZ A user records an audio with a specification in mind (a sentence, a word using a specific accent, whatever), and other users decide whether the audio passes that spec, but he doesn't need to record a new audio, only to accept it or reject by giving a reason

Comment: @Korcholis So they just accept/reject if what they hear is correct/incorrect. I would use **review**. Proofreading would require them to mark/correct all mistakes they find and help produce a better version of it, I think.

Comment: I would think that "audit" would be the obvious word.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've heard _audition_ used to describe this operation, although _sound-check_ might work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term ***proof-listen*** seems to be in use. For example:

> Proof-listening is the process of listening to a recording in order to catch recording mistakes, and verify that the file meets the technical requirements. All recordings are "prooflistened" to catch repeats, big stumbles or long pauses.
>   <sub>[LibriVox](http://wiki.librivox.org/index.php/Guide_for_Proof-listeners)</sub>

Comment: Seems perfect for me!

Answer (score 4):

The shortest word would be [vet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vet)

It means to check or evaluate for approval, correction or acceptance.

Comment: This could get confused with the short of veterinarian.

Comment: @Peanut Yes it would. But it would also prompt people to look into it and learn something new.

Comment: Despite the idea of learning something new every day is somewhat important, and although one of the exceptions of the word is somehow _review_, vet would probably not make it clear –at least at first sight

Comment: @Korcholis That is the second concern on the agenda I believe. First is to find a word that semantically fits the description. Nevertheless, you can go with "review" if nothing else.